# Razor Subexpressions in Helper Not Recognized

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I've looked and looked, but I don't think I know the right keywords to find the answer.  Here is my code:

```
@Html.ActionImage("Index", "Menu", new { menu = "@m.LinkAddr", lang = "en" }, "~/Images/@(m.MainImage)", "@m.Description")
```

Razor won't recognize any of my inner expressions (`@m.LinkAddr`, etc.). I'm using MVC4 VS2010.

Comment: Can you post the error you are getting for some added context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take your expressions out of quotes

```
@Html.ActionImage("Index", "Menu", new { menu = m.LinkAddr, lang = "en" }, "~/Images/" + m.MainImage", m.Description)
```

You also don't need the `@`, you have that at the begining of the line.

I'm assuming `m` is a variable you declared.  If these are properties on your model, use `Model`.

Comment: Ahhh . . . the entire contents of the helper signature is within Razor's bountries. Makes sense. Thanks!